# php artisan vendor:publish mervick/emojionearea

Tags: laravel

In installation no describe process publishing this package.
But I would like to setup it.

Laravel 5.6

```
composer require mervick/emojionearea ^3.0.0
```

and I need to copy from folder /vendor to /public/vendor using 
php artisan vendor:publish

I created file /vendor/mervick/emojioneareaServiceProvider.php
and added lines:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes(
            [
                __DIR__ . '/dist' => 
public_path('vendor/mervick/emojionearea/dist'),

            ],
            'emojionearea'
        );
   }
```

also, I added lines to /config/app.php

```
//ServiceProviders
Mervick\EmojioneArea\EmojioneAreaServiceProvider::class,
//Aliases
'EmojioneArea'=> Mervick\EmojioneArea\EmojioneAreaServiceProvider::class,
```

and run command :

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

also, I used the command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mervick\EmojioneArea\EmojioneAreaServiceProvider"
```

Any help.Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to happen and what is your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps i have tried moved files to public/vendor folder by updating below steps. Its works fine.

**Service provider file.**

```
<?php

namespace mervick\emojionearea;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class EmojioneAreaServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../dist' => base_path('public/vendor/dist'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your root composer.json file add your vendor for identify the service provider.

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/",
        "Mervick\\EmojioneArea\\": "vendor/mervick/emojionearea/src"
    }
}
```

Like you said don't forgot to add the service provider in config/app.php

```
Mervick\EmojioneArea\EmojioneAreaServiceProvider::class,
```

*If everything works fine for you. Please make it as correct answer.:-)*

Comment: Hi, it's no works. And I can't understand why it should be work. Because in composer.json I see folder /src , and in ServiceProvider.php I see folder /dist